# ‘Square the circle’ by rotating and enlarging inscribed square toward circumscribed

Tags: geometric-construction, transcendental-numbers

A square inscribed in a unit circle has diagonal length 2 and its area (2) forms a lower bound for pi.

A square circumscribed around a unit circle has side length 2 and its area (4) forms an upper bound for pi.

I’m imaging rotating and scaling the inscribed square so that the length ‘across’ it remains 2 but this goes from being the inscribed to circumscribed, from 2 as the diagonal to 2 as the width.

This rotation would create 4 small areas inside and 4 outside the circle. 4 Outside areas could be thought of as a kite minus a sector, 4 inside areas could be thought of as a sector minus a triangle. When the kite-sector equals the sector-triangle the area of the square would be pi. (?!).

The square that makes this happen is the square equal to the circle. I’m stuck on the algebra of these shapes / would like to see it!

Note: The square’s side lengths must be scaled up by sqrt(pi/2) but am interested to see it come about this way because of the geometric connection. Is there something special about the angle you have rotated through? Formula for the area of a square based on the angle and length of a transversal? Connection between multiplication as repeated addition (exhaustion to find pi) and rotation??

Apologies if this is already answered somewhere else in the site.

Comment: There’s no scale factor involved, since the lengths are the same. There is, however, a unique rotation sending one segment to the other. You can calculate it as you’d calculate the center of any general rotohomothety, which is something you’ll probably be able to find online.

Comment: Thanks. I can see what a homothetic centre is and imagine a rotohmothety would be. I don’t really understand the no scale factor part. The similar shapes sharing a homothetic centre aren’t all the same size, nor would they be under the rotation and enlargement I propose. Seems a good way to look at it still. The question might then be, when is one of those rotated and enlarged squares of exactly the same area as the circle surrounding the ‘original’.

Comment: What do you mean by "construct", 720014? Certainly not what Euclid meant, construct using ruler and compass.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. Yes I suppose that’s the point - I’ll look at rephrasing. If you drew all those squares from the inscribed rotating out to this circumscribed you would draw the one equal to the circle (ALL being the key word). I imagine that finding the one you need will be explicitly dependent on pi but it’s not immediately obvious me how to run the algebra to find it. I suppose the closeness to a Euclidean construction is what interests me. It’s sort of a method of exhaustion based on rotating/enlarging similar polygons  rather than more and more similar polygons.

Comment: How do you tell which of the two weird-shaped areas is larger for some arbitrary rotation of the square?

Comment: I don’t know. They depend on the angle of rotation and the increasing side length of the square (maybe goes without saying). It seems to come down to the ratio of the side inside the circle vs outside. I’m assuming that that this is the same at both ends of a side and actually all four corners because of axes symmetry. The total angle for the 4 kite-sectors is 360 - 4*(angle of sector-triangle). .?. (Might be more meaningful in radians?). The angle of the sector-triangle decreases to zero as you enlarge and rotate. Side lengths for triangle and kite (which turns into a square) are 1 (radii).

Comment: I’m getting closer with the algebra. I’ll see if I can get proper details and answer my own question https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lcooibulyg